# Testing one-sample t-test hypothesis. (R)

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

Test of the hypothesis: diet affects weight.

Test Data:(weight before and after diet)
$60;57,
65;60,
79;70,
55;60,
75;70,
60;65,
69;59,
108;101,
77;67,
88;86$

Firstly I count the difference beetween first and second column (Weight before - Weight after)

then I tried to solve this in R:

```
weight = c(3,5,9,-5,5,-5,10,7,10,2)

t.test(weight, mu=0)

    One Sample t-test

data:  weight
t = 2.3459, df = 9, p-value = 0.04359
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1464349 8.0535651
sample estimates:
mean of x 
      4.1
```

The $p-value$ is less than $.05$, so I can reject the $H_{0}$ hypothesis.
Is this correct?

Comment: It seems correct for me.

Comment: Ok, thank @callculus